# Multiselect attribute get collection of product

Tags: magento

I have a multiselect attribute "my_attribute"  with data

slot_1

slot_2

slot_3

slot_4

and, products with assigned attribute eg.

product_1 - slot_1 AND slot_3

product_2 - slot_3 AND slot_1

product_3 - slot_4 AND slot_2

product_4 - slot_1 AND slot_4

...

I would try show only product witch contains slot_1 and slot_3, In the result I should get 
product_1 and product_2 I was try accomplish this by:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')        
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute ',array('in' => array(slot_1,slot_3)))
```

but I'm get unexpected result

I read a article from [this post](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento.html) but i can't find the solution.
I'm wondering how i can solve my problem
thx for help

Comment: try `addAttributeToFilter('slot_1', array('eq' => slot_3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
addAttributeToFilter('slot_1', array('eq' => slot_3))
```